# Why do relative imports add the module I'm importing from to my namespace?

Tags: python, import, python-import

When I perform a relative import like `from .module import something`, both `something` **and** `module` are added to my namespace:

```
from .module import something
print(module) # output: <module 'package.module' from '/.../package/module.py'>
```

I expected `print(module)` to throw a NameError.

---

However, this doesn't *always* happen. Consider this package structure:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    module.py
    subpackage/
        submodule.py
        another_submodule.py
```

`module.py` contains `def function(): pass`.

`another_submodule.py` contains `something = 0`.

`submodule.py` contains

```
from .another_submodule import something
stuff = 0
```

`__init__.py` contains

```
from .module import function
from .subpackage.submodule import stuff

print('"module" in package?', 'module' in globals())
print('"subpackage" in package?', 'subpackage' in globals())
print('"submodule" in package?', 'submodule' in globals())
print('"submodule" in subpackage?', 'submodule' in subpackage.__dict__)
print('"another_submodule" in submodule?', 'another_submodule' in subpackage.submodule.__dict__)
```

Running `import package` produces this output:

```
"module" in package? True
"subpackage" in package? True
"submodule" in package? False
"submodule" in subpackage? True
"another_submodule" in submodule? False
```

As we can see here, `another_submodule` doesn't get imported into `submodule`, even though it performs a relative import.

---

What is going on here? Is this a bug or a documented feature?